# How can I cache Windows updates localy

Tags: windows-update

I have an office with about 100 or so users. I have to bring new laptops up by fresh installing office every so often (2-3 a week) and it seems silly to me that I have to download them fresh each time

Is there a way I can cache them locally ( I have 3 windows server 2012 r2 servers but I don't see any roles that look like they apply to this)

Comment: You can [this](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) there are other tools of course and other methods.

Comment: check wuinstall /download_cache and /install_cache options att http://www.wuinstall.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role or feature you’re looking for is called Windows Server Update Services (WSUS for short).

Here’s Microsoft’s official [admin guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852345.aspx) about WSUS on Windows Server 2012/2012 R2.